# write text file with simultaneous random access and append

Tags: c++, file-io

The following piece of code tries to overwrite to different locations in a file and also to append to the file. However, it does not seem to work. I have tried several modes and the result is either overwriting or simply appending everything to the end of the file but not both together. Is it possible to do such a thing in C++? Or, is it that we need to open the file again and again in different modes to accomplish this?

```
int main() {
  fstream f("a.dat", ios::out | ios::app);
  f.seekp(ios::beg);
  f << "hello world";
  f.seekp(ios::end);
  f << "works";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: May not be relevant for your usage, but worth pointing out that, IIRC, in the append mode the OS itself provides some sync between write requests to the file, so each writer's content is guaranteed to get in there in some order.  If you append yourself in any other mode, you need to consider race conditions where you find the end, then some other process write at the end, then you write and end up clobbering the other process's or thread's data.  If this is an issue for you, you may indeed want to close/reopen the file, or have two distinct handles - only one using append mode.

Comment: @Tony Could what you say possibly mean that c++ does not provide such a thing as I am looking for?

Comment: C++ - or any language - can only provide access to the operating system features for file manipulation (unless you're writing the filesystem driver itself).  On most operating systems, there's a special append mode that handles race conditions between processes/threads, and as you know C++ lets you use it.  If that doesn't suit you, but you will have race conditions, then you have to do the sync yourself... using say a mutex in shared memory between cooperating processes, or a mutex anywhere if there's just a bunch of threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specify `ios::app` when you open the file all writes will always go to the end of the file -- it's basically as if *every* write was preceded by `f.seekp(ios::end)`.

It sounds like what you want is `ios::ate` instead. This will seek to the end of the file immediately after it's opened, but when/if you seek to somewhere else in the file and write, the write will go to the current point in the file instead of the end.

Edit 3: I've added code to seek back to the end and append more there:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    std::fstream f("test.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios_base::ate);

     f << " added to end.";
     f.seekp(0, std::ios::beg);
     f << "Original";
     f.seekp(0, std::ios::end);
     f << " Final.";

     return 0;
}
```

Starting with the following as the content of the file "test.txt":

```
Initial  Value.
```

After running the program, the file should contain:

```
Original value. added to end. Final.
```

So, "Added to end." gets, obviously enough, added to the end. We then seek back to the beginning, and overwrite 'Initial" (plus one of the two spaces after it) with "Original".

As an aside, I should add that I was apparently at least half asleep when I posted last night -- I completely missed the fact that you had only supplied on parameter when you called `seekp`. With only one parameter, it takes that as the offset into the file. Unfortunately, `std::ios::beg`, `std::ios::cur` and `std::ios::end` are simple integer values, so instead of giving a type error (as you'd really like) it was simply taking the *value* of those enumerations, and using them as offsets into the file. Purely by luck, `std::ios::beg` apparently has the value 0 (at least on my implementation) so it "worked", but only by accident. With two parameters (as the code above has now) the first is the offset, and the second it the reference point (beginning, current position or end) from which that offset starts.

Comment: @Jerry The final result I get in the file with your code is `New    to end.`.It seems the values were overwritten. I got this result after removing ios::in from your code. Running your code as is gave me `New     Value`. I am using g++.

Comment: @r.v: My apologies -- I screwed up the editing. I believe it's fixed now. I've tested this with both VC++ and g++, and gotten the same results. As noted above, however, this expects to start with some content already in the file. Without that, you need to remove `std::ios::in` for it to work, and it should produce "Originalo end."

Comment: @Jerry You are right. This works. Yet, if I move the put pointer to ios::again, it does not append but rather overwrites. For example, after writing in `Original` if I say `f.seekp(std::ios::end); f<< " Finally";`. It appears even more complicated now.

Comment: @Jerry Thanks for the code. One more question. Using std::ios::in in the file open mode seems to be essential even though we are not reading from the file. If I do not use this flag I get different results. It leaves me wondering what is happening either at the language level or at the OS level. Can you throw more light on that?

Comment: @r.v: even though you're not using data from the file, behind the scenes it's still reading the data. A typical disk only allows reading or writing data in multiples of sector-sized chunks. To modify data in a sector, it has to do a read/modify/write cycle.

Comment: @Jerry Thanks. This makes some sense to me.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking to insert data somewhere in the file that is not the end? There is no insertion, at least with `fstream`s, in my experience. This is much like writing data in an array. Simply having a pointer somewhere between the beginning and end of the array and writing there doesn't insert, it overwrites.

Handle it like you would inserting data into the middle of an array. You have to move data forward to make space for the insertion.

Calculate how much space you'll need for the insertion and read all data after the insertion point to a buffer, the write the data in that buffer back into the file after you've moved your write pointer forward by the amount of space you'll need for the insertion. Then, move your write pointer back to where you wanted to insert and write the data you plan to insert.

1. Calculate insertion data length.
2. Seek to insertion point.
3. Read rest of file to buffer.
4. Seek to insertion point.
5. Write insertion data.
6. Write from rest of file buffer.

EDIT:
The requested code example:

```
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::fstream FileStream;

    // Initial write.
    FileStream.open("Test.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
    FileStream << "OLDDATAOLDDATA";
    FileStream.close();

    // Prepare data to insert.
    const char InsertionData[] = "newdata";
    const unsigned int InsertionDataLength = strlen(InsertionData);

    // Insertion write.
    FileStream.open("Test.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::ate);

    std::ios::pos_type InsertionPosition = 7; // 7 is the start index of the second "OLDDATA".
    FileStream.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::ios::pos_type EndPosition = FileStream.tellg();

    // Read rest of file.
    const unsigned int RestOfFileDataLength = EndPosition - InsertionPosition;
    char* const RestOfFileData = new char[RestOfFileDataLength];
    FileStream.seekg(InsertionPosition);
    FileStream.read(RestOfFileData, RestOfFileDataLength);

    // Rewrite rest of file.
    FileStream.seekp(InsertionPosition);
    FileStream.write(InsertionData, InsertionDataLength);
    FileStream.write(RestOfFileData, RestOfFileDataLength);
    delete[] RestOfFileData;

    FileStream.close();
}
```

A few notes. The earlier in the file that you insert, the more expensive it is because you need to move everything after it. That also means bigger files are more expensive to insert into. If you're going to do several inserts, you can try to keep track of each insertion and defer them until some kind of flush command is called, at which point only 1 major read/write of the rest of the file is necessary, instead of one for each insertion call. Ideally, you should wrap this up in your own wrapper of some sort.

Comment: Perhaps I did not make it clear in my question. I have edited it now. It is not insertions that I want. I just want to overwrite at different locations and also simultaneously append to the file. I was expecting these two to be possible together. In any case, what you say also seems to be expanding the file, perhaps by appending (you are not creating a new file, right?). Could you give me a working sample code for that?

Comment: @r.v Sample added. No new file necessary. This shows off the basic insertion logic. Mind you that each insertion is expensive. Ideally, you would buffer all of your insertions and defer them until the end, because each read-&-write-rest-of-file gets increasingly expensive as the file is bigger and the insertion point is earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the sample. I see that you are able to expand the file without needing a new file and may be able to use such a thing in my code.

Answer (score 1):

What you'll need to know:

- Append mode writes to the end of the file, no matter what seeking you may do
- Even in other writing modes, writing at the beginning of the file does not prepend, it overwrites.  This is not the "fault" of C++ so much as it is the filesystem.  It's just the way file manipulation works, and will be the case for just about every platform and every language out there.
- If you really want to insert text in other places, you'll probably need to read the file into memory, manipulate it, then re-write the file to disk.  Or in some cases it might make sense to use something like `sed` to manipulate the file.

Languages that provide file preprend capabilities out of the box are rare.  I don't know of any that do, unless you count special purpose languages like `sed` that aren't good for anything *but* file manipulation.  There may be languages that do what you want in the way you were hoping, but I don't know of any.

Comment: I see that there must be some OS/FS constraints due to which c++ is not allowing something. I just needed to overwrite and also to append to file. Append by itself is allowed. But is it possible to append and also (in the same mode) overwrite at different places in file?